# Is there a way to play all YouTube videos uploaded by a particular user?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

For example, I want to play all 58 videos uploaded by a single user.

Obviously I could create a playlist, add each video to it, then play the entire playlist, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Currently there seems to be no way to do this. Besides creating the playlist yourself.

Comment: I created a bookmarklet that seems to work pretty universally in the current year, whether the user has a public 'Uploads' playlist on their page or not, but Stack Exchange's awesome preventative measures from allowing people to answer questions makes it impossible for me to post it, even after logging back in to my account from like 2014. Nice.

Answer (score 49):

URL hacking for the rescue! You can append `&list=UL` to the end of a video URL from that user.

So, if you have:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucBfXpCA6s
```

it should become:

[`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucBfXpCA6s&list=UL`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucBfXpCA6s&list=UL)

```
                                           ^ right here
```

You could also add something like this to your bookmark and simply click on it:

```
javascript:window.location+='&list=UL'
```

*Select* it then *drag and drop* it on your bookmarks. ([how?](https://support-staging.aodocs.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/206777023/How_to_install_bookmarklets.gif))

Now, **there is an issue**!

It's got a weird behaviour as dear @burtek brought to my attention on the comments.

In my instance here, with Valentina Lisitsa, she got 272 videos right now, but it won't ever show more than 99 on the list. And it seems like it's ordered from oldest to newest, so if you want to play all videos you rather start with the user's first video. In her case, this is it:

[`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS_foc_NxI0&list=UL`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS_foc_NxI0&index=180&list=UL)

From there you can leave it playing and it will play all her videos.

Seemed like the current video will always try to be in position #20 of the list, showing 19 previous ones and 79 next ones, but now I believe it's even more random than that.

Most users, however, do have an "uploads" section on their profile, and you can just click on "Play All" right there to get a generated playlist from newest to oldest, like @wisbucky pointed in another answer here:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82675/4616

Comment: And it includes only a few of the user's videos

Comment: @burtek what you mean?

Comment: When I add `&list=UL` to the address of the video, the opened playlist contains only 21 videos. The channel has more than 140 videos.

Comment: @burtek mind sharing the link? Maybe the channel has videos the user haven't uploaded... But maybe this just doesn't work as I'd expect as well!

Comment: Sure. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWMBsK6lV1k&list=UL.
Also here's the screenshot: http://zapisz.net/images/757_yt.png.
`153 filmy` means `153 videos` ;)

Comment: It is way more buggy than we would expect indeed, @burtek. Thanks for bringing my attention to this. I've edited the answer! ;-)

Comment: How did you find out about the `&list=UL` bit?

Comment: @confused00 I don't recall. I think I was looking around trying to find an answer to this question and eventually ended up  realizing youtube had this way to view such a playlist. Figuring out the url bit from there was trivial, if you know how they work.

Comment: @Cawas Fair enough. How did you come up with `UL` though? Where'd you get it from? Typing it lowercase doesn't seem to work, so I suppose it wasn't just guesswork?

Comment: @confused00 that's my point. If you go right now to [Valentina's channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6UbiyGEGkF5iuqKRsShCOg) and find `Uploads` you'll see there a `Play All` button. Back when I wrote this answer, that would lead to that `list=UL`. Now it's leading to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuFJ06wtcmM&list=UU6UbiyGEGkF5iuqKRsShCOg` and I didn't dig more to know why it's this different now. Just trying to illustrate how I might have done it in that past. ;)

Comment: @Cawas Oh I see! Many thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Stack Exchange only [allows limited information in HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/21960). That's why you can't create the full link here.

Comment: @ale thanks for editing it out. i should probably have left that comment in the comments section in the first place! :) i was actually already aware of that faq, but still don't know why we couldn't at least use the code snippet plugin or something to allow adding some `javascript` candies such as this. then again, never bothered me enough to even ask it in meta! ;P

Comment: It doesn't work anymore

Comment: @rainb good thing we are starting to see better alternatives to youtube, such as lbry and even tiktok (which isn't really better, but sure feels like). most things google are starting to break because they're all based in broken models. be sure to take a step back and look around! ,

Comment: @cregox videos of at least 60 seconds long are probably not really immersive,

Comment: @rainb that's one of the minor reasons why i said **even** tiktok. the 1 minute limitation makes it the twitter of videos, and is very valuable for that. fwiw, it ends being much more immersive than youtube, as long as you're watching in your hands and swiping up for things you want to skip. i never spent so much time on any kind of tube as i do on tiktok, and i've been most of my life on the internet, since before the web. but, by all means, **please** let's collectively work on things like lbry instead! take a deep look into that!!

Answer (score 27):

Much easier way now:

1. Go to the user's Youtube home page (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/user/xyz/ ).
2. Hover over the "Uploads" section. You will see a "Play all" button appear next to "Uploads".
3. Click on "Play all" and it will generate a playlist with all the user's uploaded videos from newest to oldest. (I just wish there was an easy option to sort from oldest to newest)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "Play All" button.  Was this removed?  Care to add a screenshot?

Comment: @Yuck, I added a screenshot. On some user home pages, the "Uploads" section doesn't show up, so then it's not possible. But it's there for most users.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  It's actually my mistake anyway.  I was on the "Videos" tab which shows "Uploads" but doesn't have the button to Play All.  When I am on a user's main page I do see the button.

Comment: fwiw, in the new design there *is* a "play all" button on the /videos page, in the current design (the one seen in the screenshot), the channel in question needs to have the "recent uploads" playlist featured on their channel.

Comment: It only plays about 12 videos.

Comment: Tried this with Stephen Colbert - who has over 5000 videos.  I wish this would work

Comment: It's the real answer!

Comment: It's up to the channel user if he includes the Uploads playlist, and this is obviously no use in scripting.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, does it.

Answer (score 16):

It's subtle, and it's cheeky, but it can be done:

Given a particular channel URL:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9mPk8yIk1AUC8PDsUYFBaA

You can fiddle a little bit and:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UU9mPk8yIk1AUC8PDsUYFBaA

Note that you change `channel/UC` to `playlist?list=UU`.

`$ echo "$URL" | sed 's/channel\/UC/playlist\?list=UU/'`

You don't need to have a particular video.

The playlist can't be sorted, saved or manipulated in any useful way (at time of writing), but when you hit "Play all" or pick a video you can use the shuffle button  in the playlist.

Comment: This works for me

Comment: Almost worked on https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUMtFAi84ehTSYSE9XoHefig  But as soon as I hit Play All, it switches to a different UI and drops out of the playlist

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: This is the only method on this page that worked for me in 2021

Comment: Can also confirm it works

Comment: This method *does* work and gives you the Uploads playlist, even if it is hidden. However, you can't get the channel ID from the URL of the page, since there's like 3 or 4 different canonical URL types for channels which are preferred by the site over channel/UCxxx, so this doesn't *always* work.

Comment: 2022-11 and apparently this still works, unlike other methods stated here. Would anyone care to explain how the query parameters work? Those UU, UL, UC things are a bit weird.

Comment: 2023-08 - still works, though I needed the tip from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/61391/315480 to find the channel ID (the one I was looking for had a speaking username)

Comment: 2024 03-15 Still works. Note the URL presented uses the name ID, I had to open up dev tools and search for /channel/ and after copying a few of the results I found the correct one for the channel. Then I used the trick described in this answer and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

You could also use this site here: http://youtube.nestharion.de

It creates a playlist with all the videos from a user and plays them continually.

Comment: At the moment, I need to opt out of the HTML5 trial to use this playlist generator.

Comment: If like me you don't want to opt out of the HTML5 trial, just open another browser window, as this answer works for any non-logged-in user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The site also mentions using this url instead : http://youtube.nestharion.de/ If the link from the answer goes offline, this one should work.

Comment: Is there a way to open the playlist on youtube, or save it to resume playing later?

Comment: this site is dangerous now, my avast antivirus warns against it.

Comment: doesn't work with Stephen Colbert

Answer (score 11):

Little trick I found is to get a user's unique code/string from their profile page's source.  Here's how to do it:

- Go to their user page and right-click -> "view page source".
- Search for "vnd" and copy the code that you find (It should start with "UC").
- Open one of the user's videos.  In the URL address, add the following to the end: "&list=" then paste the string you copied.
- Final step is simply change the 2nd character of the code you pasted from a C to a U.  Hit enter and the video should reload, and now it appears in a playlist of all the user's videos.

This seems to work pretty reliably, but sometimes does not get all of the user's videos.

Comment: Is not necessary to check the source, just the link to the user in any of the videos should be enough.

Comment: Wow this one actually lets you play videos newest-to-oldest instead of the oldest-to-newest with `&list=UL`

Comment: This is the only one that still works. Thank you. YouTube has made it hard lately to get the `^UC.*` channel URL.

Answer (score 0):

## 2024 Update with explanation

I recently created a small userscript called [YouTube Play All](https://github.com/RobertWesner/YouTube-Play-All/tree/main) to add the now missing `Play All` button back to YouTube. Below I will explain how it works in detail so you may reproduce it without usage of the userscript.

This approach is based on [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/113913/324904) but modified to work with recent changes since the release of YouTube shorts. The issue in 2024 is the general lack of a `Play All` button in a channels videos tab. Without changes to YouTube, the only way to directly access a playlist with all videos is having the creator add it to their home tab. Unfortunately, not all YouTube channels have this playlist accessible.

[image: Missing play all button][image: Manually added playlist by creator]

The playlist for `Uploads by <User>` can easily be accessed through the channel ID. As example, I will use the channel [Cathode Ray Dude [CRD]](https://www.youtube.com/@CathodeRayDude) due to it both containing videos and shorts.

Inside the HTML body of a YouTube channel **videos section**, one can find the `link[rel="canonical"]` containing a full link to the channel with the ID:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXnNibvR_YIdyPs8PZIBoEw">
```

A very important note is this link element possibly being out of date when switching between multiple channels. YouTube will keep the old link with the ID of the previously visited channel, so a refresh of your page is recommended before extracting the ID.

The ID `XnNibvR_YIdyPs8PZIBoEw` can now be used to access a playlist by prepending `UU` and using it as the `list` GET parameter, for example in:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUXnNibvR_YIdyPs8PZIBoEw
```

This now shows the playlist "Uploads from Cathode Ray Dude [CRD]".

As of 2024, the `UU` playlist includes YouTube shorts, which might not be desired and differs from the default videos playlist you can find on some channels. To remedy this you should use `UULF` as prefix which only includes long form videos. So the link to the playlist now looks like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UULFXnNibvR_YIdyPs8PZIBoEw
```

Now showing a playlist simply titled "Videos":
[image: Videos playlist]

Of course, this can not only be used to just view the playlist but directly added as parameter to a video like his [newest upload](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PkIh5IsqyY):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PkIh5IsqyY&list=UULFXnNibvR_YIdyPs8PZIBoEw
                                           ^- added as GET parameter
```

---

To save time and effort, I recommend the previously mentioned userscript available [here](https://github.com/RobertWesner/YouTube-Play-All/tree/main), as it automatically adds a button with the correct link and doesn't require additional refreshes of the page.
[image: Demo of the YouTube Play All userscript]

Answer (score -1):

The Firefox add-on called [YouTube Play All](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/222206/) seems to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

just put `javascript:Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("addto-watch-later-button")).forEach(function(element, index, array){array[index].click();})`
in url and hit enter, it adds every video on the current page to watch later list, nasty but it works.
Goto ther videos page, click the load mores and use it.

Comment: this works better since it spaces out the network requests by 100ms: `avascript:Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("addto-watch-later-button")).forEach(function(element, index, array){setTimeout(function(a){a.click();}, index * 100, array[index])})`

Answer (score -1):

If you have subscribed to the user, Youtube TV is an alternative: 
https://www.youtube.com/tv

All you need to do is link your account with the app. No apps, plugins, or 3rd party webapps needed.

Comment: This works but the audio controls are disabled if you're using a desktop browser.

Comment: a am redirecting to youtube.com

Answer (score -1):

Here's a bookmarklet & code for uploads playlist. Copy and save the line below as a bookmark, open a YouTube video and click the bookmark to load the user's uploads playlist. I don't think a public or auto-generated playlist of all uploads exists, only recent uploads, which is the same as what you see when you click play in the corner of a user's playlist called uploads, and the same you'll find by using this bookmarklet

**Bookmark:**

```
javascript:(function()%7Bif%20(window.location.href.indexOf(%22watch%3Fv%3D%22)%20%3E%20-1%20%26%26%20window.location.href.indexOf(%22%26list%3D%22)%20%3C%200)%20%7Bwindow.location%20%2B%3D%20%22%26list%3D%22%20%2B%20%22UU%22%20%2B%20document.documentElement.innerHTML.match('channelId%22%20content%3D%22(.*%3F)%22')%5B1%5D.substr(2)%3B%7D%7D)()
```

**Javascript:**

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("watch?v=") > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("&list=") < 0) {
  window.location += "&list=" + "UU" + document.documentElement.innerHTML.match('channelId" content="(.*?)"')[1].substr(2);
}
```

Note, as mentioned on this page, simply appending "&list=UL" to the video URL doesn't work as desired.

Also worth mentioning this only really works if you load the channel's latest video then use the bookmark

Credit for the bookmarklet method goes to REast and [his comment below](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/#61391).

Answer (score -1):

This is a much simpler way...

Just go to the uploads tab of the YouTube channel, then press "Play all"

[image]

That should play the playlist of all videos from a channel

Comment: Already stated https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82675/